# Change the value of an item given a flag

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame which holds bets placed on horses, with each row being a new bet. Each bet has multiple attributes including location, the name of the horse, winnings/losses etc.
The problem is those bet winnings are given in a positive integer and a flag attribute is provided to say whether it is a win or a loss.

This is the data frame provided:

```
    Race Course                 Horse  Year  Month  Date  Amount Won/Lost
0       Aintree               Red Rum  2017      5    12   11.58      won
1   Punchestown               Camelot  2016     12    22  122.52      won
2       Sandown        Beef of Salmon  2016     11    17   20.00     lost
3           Ayr              Corbiere  2016     11     3   25.00     lost
4    Fairyhouse               Red Rum  2016     12     2   65.75      won
5           Ayr               Camelot  2017      3    11   12.05      won
6       Aintree         Hurricane Fly  2017      5    12   11.58      won
7   Punchestown        Beef or Salmon  2016     12    22  112.52      won
8       Sandown              Aldaniti  2016     11    17   10.00     lost
9           Ayr   Henry the Navigator  2016     11     1   15.00     lost
10   Fairyhouse               Jumanji  2016     10     2   65.75      won
11          Ayr           Came Second  2017      3    11   12.05      won
12      Aintree                Murder  2017      5    12    5.00    lost
13  Punchestown           King Arthur  2016      6    22   52.52      won
14      Sandown         Filet of Fish  2016     11    17   20.00     lost
15          Ayr                Denial  2016     11     3   25.00     lost
16   Fairyhouse          Don't Gamble  2016     12    12  165.75      won
17          Ayr               Ireland  2017      1    11   22.05      won
```

And I need to create a data frame of the following format:

```
Year        Total Won   Total Lost
2016        €123.45     €678.90
2017        €543.21     €987.60
```

I have been trying to iterate through the columns as well as tried using the where function but cannot seem to get anything to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `groupby`, `sum`, and then unstack the result:

```
df.groupby(['Year', 'Won/Lost'])['Amount'].sum().unstack(-1).add_prefix('total_')

Won/Lost  total_lost  total_won
Year                           
2016           115.0     584.81
2017             5.0      69.31
```

Comment: thank you this was far more efficient than any of my attempts, how can I remove the won/lost heading in the top left corner

Comment: @TomWalsh You can run `result.columns.name = None`

Comment: Also it turns out my orginal code would have worked, however my csv had extra white space around the values which was throwing off my lookups